# eval-after-load does not execute the forms

Tags: emacs, elisp

As per the elisp docs http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks-for-Loading.html the **eval-after-load** should evaluate the forms irrespective of the library(in this case its "org") is loaded or not. But the following expression does not seem to have any effect on the form (message "HELLO").

```
(eval-after-load "org" '(message "HELLO"))
```

The expected result is to find the string "HELLO" printed on the *Message* buffer which does not seems to happen.

Comment: Works for me. Maybe you're not loading the line. Try to eval it from `*scratch*`.

Comment: Thanks for testing and reporting. Using compiled emacs version 24.3.1 in ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine. Tried to eval from *scratch* and the result is the same. Any thoughts on how to debug this issue.

Comment: Does `C-j` in `*scratch*` result in nil or "HELLO"?

Comment: Is `org` actually loaded?  You can check with `(featurep 'org)`.

Comment: The result of eval (featurep 'org) is nil.However C-h f org-<TAB> displays all the org-* functions in *Completions* buffer. I was under the impression that completions can happen only if the module is loaded, which seems not the case

Comment: They're probably autoloaded, that's why they're in completions. Just require 'org or call one of those functions

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I was following the magnars(author of www.emacsrocks.com)  setup https://github.com/magnars/.emacs.d/blob/master/init.el and it seems in his file he does not do any require('org). No idea how it works for him.

Comment: Probably autoloading. First call to an autoloaded org function will require org. And you don't need to require org if you're not using org functions.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit, the form is NOT executed irrespective of whether the library is loaded or not. The form will be evaluated whenever the library is loaded. If the library is already loaded it will evaluate the form immediately. In case of Magnar's config, the org-setup.el is not 'require'd immediately rather it is 'require'd whenever org is loaded.

Comment: @IqbalAnsari Thanks. That was exactly the problem. So the solution seems to be to use "require" instead of "eval-after-load" to immediate load.

Comment: OK then I will post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have misunderstood the manual, the form is **not** executed irrespective of whether the library is loaded or not. The form will be evaluated whenever the library is loaded. If the library is already loaded it will evaluate the form immediately. In case of Magnar's config, the org-setup.el is not 'require'd immediately rather it is 'require'd whenever org is loaded.

Comment: Yes, `eval-after-load` is not for *loading* libraries; it is for *reacting* to libraries being loaded.